# algorithm to change the center of the image

Tags: java, mathematics, geometry

I need and algorithm in Java if possible to change the center of the image when scaling.What is happening to me is represented in the first image:
when I scale the image the image scale according to the center point of the image, what I want to do is on image2, I want to create a point A and make the image scale using that point on the horizontal line (y=540).

I have the screen size(1920x1080) the horizontal line y=540, the length and width of the rectangle, image_X=0,image_Y=0 will put the center point o x=0 and y=0, (on the image example x=1000)

Every time I do scale_image=2 the image is reduced to half the size, which is fine but it does that using center point. What I want to do is to adjust image_Y so it uses point A as the new center.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Adding the code could help us help you better.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "transforms": scale, translate, rotate, etc. You have a *scale* operation which causes A to move to a different position. Scale is multiply: `new_y = (old_y - center_y) / 2 + center_y`. You want A to stay the same. You'll want a *translate* operation afterwards to move A back to the desired y position. Translate is add: `newer_y = new_y + something`. If you work through the scale operation, `new_A_y = (old_A_y _ center_y) / 2 + center_y`, you can then add `old_A_y - new_A_y` to the y value to move it back into the place you want (I haven't tested this).